# java.lang.illegalstateexception: Unknown protocol: http

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

After running a simple code in my android app for sending some data to a server i receive this exception:
java.lang.illegalstateexception: Unknown protocol: http

This is  the code:

```
        URL url = new URL("http://myserver");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(myString.toString());
        out.close();
```

I tried this using an Async task.
Also I get this error with whatever url i use (e.g http://www.google.com).

The internet permissions are set in manifest file.

Any help?

Comment: Try replacing `URL url = new URL(http://myserver);` with `URL url = new URL("http://myserver");`

Comment: This is how i use it in code. I just place it like this in the question. 
     
any other suggestion?

Comment: can you share more descriptive log ? That would be of great help to you and to the community.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this

```
URL url = new URL(http://myserver);
```

to this

```
URL url = new URL("http://myserver");
```

Comment: This is how i use it in code. I just place it like this in the question.

Comment: any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't declared the permission, you have to add the permissions in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Doesn't help. I have already set the permissions in manifest file.

Comment: I think you would need to post more information, including the stack trace and the manifest file